# Lookup fields appear with the Lookup button on record edit pages

Tags: apex, visualforce, lookup, dynamic-visualforce, lookup-filter

Lookup fields appear with the Lookup button[image]
 on record edit pages

How can i make it in my VF Page ?

Comment: did you get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Standard lookup field or any other field with **apex:inputField** tag. You will get lookup icon easily.

otherwise you need to go with [custom lookup icon](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/) and try this approach . But if you are using standard field then then `apex:inputfield` is better option.

Comment: Can you give me any example ?

Comment: `<apex:inputField value="{!objContact.AccountId}"`/>
it will create input field with lookup icon.